# MySql - Using variables in select query and where condition gives one more additional row

Tags: mysql, variables

I am using variables in select query to calculate a value and based on the value I have added where condition in query.

What my problem in it gives addtional one more row whatever field value is.

For example if the field value is 1 on all rows in that table then it gives 20 plus additional one more row 21.

Kindly help in solving this issue.

How to add condtion based on value calculated as I can't use SUM, it will aggregate and returns only one value.

Below is sample query I use.

```
SET @var = 0;
SELECT  @var := @var + field FROM table1 WHERE  @var <= 20
```

Comment: *`WHERE  @var <= 20`* Last `@var` value when this condition is TRUE is equal to `20`. Do you remember that WHERE condition is checked before output expression evaluation?

Comment: @Akina How to solve this issue. I used HAVING but still same issue only.

Comment: Please post THE TASK. Not the way which you decide to use for to solve this task. And - what is your MySQL version?

Comment: @Akina MySql version 5.5.45. I was trying to get rows from table which met the condition.Table is my Purchase table where I have field named purchase_qty which is in grams. If my input value is 20 I just have to retrive all the rows upto 20 grams. I want each row seperately upto the input value I give.

Comment: If so then your query is wrong by default - it have no ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

> MySql version 5.5.45

Check for

```sql
SELECT t1.(fieldset)
FROM source_table t1
JOIN source_table t2 ON t1.ordering_field <= t2.ordering field
GROUP BY t1.(fieldset)
HAVING SUM(t2.amount_field) <= @needed_sum
ORDER BY SUM(t2.amount_field) DESC [LIMIT 1]
```

Comment: Thank you so much.